# Undeclared identifier custom class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, compiler-errors

`'Plansza' : undeclared identifier`
I don't know why i get this error. I have 2 classes called "Plansza" and "GameData", i have included both headers( in Plansza.h included "GameData.h" and it's works, but when I include "Plansza.h" in GameData.h it does not see Plansza class :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include `A.h` in `B.h` and ALSO the other way around, you setup **a circular dependence**. If you had include guards, **one of them gets lost** and such errors occur.

What you want to do is try hard to include `.h` files in the `.cpp` files as far as possible, and if this is not possible, reduce the 2 way dependence into a 1 way dependence.

Try as often as possible to **use forward declarations** in the `.h` files, as long as you are using only pointers to the class, this will suffice.

```
class Plansza;
```

instead of

```
#include "Plansza.h"
```

Edit: Thanks user1701595 for a very good reference - [Organizing Code Files in C and C++](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798)

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798

Comment: You need to move all function definitions to the .cpp. They need the entire definition of the class. Just the declaration however needs just a forward declaration in the .h

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this question, and does *not* have cyclical includes, I managed to get this exact same error by naming an enum case the exact same thing as my Class name.